# Intuitive reason for why $U^\perp$ is a subspace of $V$ for any $U \subseteq V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So for a subspace $U$ of $V$, I have some geometric visualization of how the orthogonal complement $U^\perp$ is a subspace of $V$. For example, if $U$ is a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $U^\perp$ is the line normal to that plane. However, it is true in general that $U^\perp$ is a subspace of $V$ whenever $U$ is any subset of $V$. This might be harder to visualize. For example if $U$ just consists of a bunch of random points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, why is $U^\perp$ a subspace? My reasoning is as follows: for any vector $u \in U$, it is going to have a plane orthogonal to it (or all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, if $u = 0$). So, $U^\perp$ is like the intersection of all these planes (which are subspaces). Since the arbitrary intersection of subspaces is a subspace, $U^\perp$ is a subspace.

Is this a general way we can think about things? Does it basically follow from the fact that we have universal quantifiers? (E.g. in the definition of $U^\perp$, we want vectors that are orthogonal to *all* of $U$). It reminds me also of how the annihilator of a subset is a subspace. Or how sometimes we think of the “smallest” subset as being the intersection over all possible sets. Like the span of some vectors is the “smallest” subspace generated by those vectors, i.e. it is the intersection over all subspaces containing those vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see more to it than just this:

If $x,y\in V$ are such that $\langle x,u\rangle=0$ and $\langle y,u\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U$ then it follows from the **bilinearity of the inner product** that $\langle \lambda x+y,u\rangle=0$ for all $u\in U$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a non zero vector $u$  in $R^3$
. Then there is a geometrical description of $u$.
Specifically, $u^{\perp}$ is the plane in $R^3$ through the origin $O$ and perpendicular to the vector $u$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your observations are all good: It it true that the orthogonal complement of a point is a subspace and that the orthogonal complement of a set is the intersection of the orthogonal complements of all of its points. And that this is an intersection is directly related to the "for all" in the definition.

Not sure what else you want to hear...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just thought it was interesting because I've never heard it defined that way before. I was wondering if this is a general strategy for defining things or way of looking at things.

Comment: @twosigma, I guess this is one of those things where, if you would point them out to a beginner, they would find it abstract and not helpful, but at a certain level they are obvious.